# What is console.h?

Tags: visual-c++, console

I have seen quite a few example programs that are based upon the console.h command. I have searched Google but I have not found a good tutorial on how to use this command. Dose anyone have a good, interesting, and in depth tutorial for me? *I am using VS 2010 C++

Comment: When I try to do #include "Console.h" it says it cannot find the specified source file. Why is this?

Comment: There's never any lack of book examples or class libraries that extend the rather limited teletype-style I/O that's available from the standard C and C++ libraries.  It is not a standard .h file, nobody can help you find it if you don't say where you saw it being used.

Comment: It was being used in this tutorial: http://www.kathekonta.com/rlguide/article1.html

Comment: If it's not a standard file how can i add it?

Comment: And that's exactly what it is.  Just click on the download link at the bottom of the page.

Comment: but when I try to run the file i can see it fine in the editor but the #include "Console.h" is underlined in red. What I meant was how can I add the console.h file to my list of sources (#include"s)?

Comment: You have to tell the compiler where the file is located.  Simplest way to do that is to just copy it into your project directory.

Comment: One more little question. Will I have to add the .lib and .h files to every single project I make or now that I have added it once it will stay there?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. You need to get the folders in the example program and move them to the VS C++ folder. Sorry about the stupid question.